# LineageOS stuck in boot animation

Tags: android

I got a new FairPhone 2 today, and I followed [this guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/FP2/install)

I got the latest TWRP (twrp-3.2.3-0-FP2.img) - and I can get into recovery mode fine.

I sideloaded the latest build for Fairphone 2 (lineage-15.1-20190327-nightly-FP2-signed.zip), and immediately after I sideloaded MindTheGapps-8.1.0-arm-20180808_153837.zip.

I then rooted by installing addonsu-15.1-arm-signed.zip.

I rebooted and I get the bubble going from right to left forever. Can someone help me with this?